# How do I use query the youtube data api from localhost in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api, localhost, youtube-data-api

Here's my current request code (I'm using bluebird).

```
request.getAsync('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=all+time+low&key=AIzaSyDaHcw5b3PPbw60RPsscYnT0qKeRfesn0s').then(function(results){
    console.log("results:", results[0].body);
});
```

I always get:

```
"code": 403,
"message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
```

I've tried adding everything I could think of to my refer ips but nothing seems to work?
Do I have to do something special to set this up?

things I've tried with no success:

```
localhost/*
127.0.0.1/*
localhost:1337/*
192.168.1.120
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: you should give your real IP

Comment: Thank you.
You are my hero.
Why I couldn't think of that I do not know